# Dynamic component binding leads to endless loop

Tags: vuejs2

When I use the following snippet to try to load components dynamically, the site respectively the import runs endless loop.

```js
<template>
  <div>
    <div v-for="(user, userIndex) in users" :key="userIndex">
      <component 
        :is="() => import(`./${user.typ}CreateFields.vue`)" 
        v-model="users[userIndex]"
      />
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

Isn't it possible to have the dynamic component in an loop?

Here's the sandbox:
https://codesandbox.io/s/nice-thunder-2yjhp3?file=/src/App.vue

And the error page (see in console):
https://2yjhp3.csb.app/

### Solution

I finally found a solution thanks to the comments. I created a middle-component that takes over the async loading:

```js
<template>
  <component :is="myComponent" v-model="val" />
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { Component, Vue, Prop } from 'vue-property-decorator';

@Component
export default class BeanstandetePositionCreateFields extends Vue {
    @Prop({ required: true })
    public value!: MyObject;

    public get val() {
        return this.value;
    }

    public set val(value: BeanstandetePositionCreate) {
        this.$emit('input', value);
    }

    public get myComponent() {
        const typ = this.val.typ;
        return () => import(`./${typ}CreateFields.vue`);
    }
}
</script>
```

Then the loop works.

Comment: Please post your answer ***as an answer***, not an edit to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue you're facing is because you're using a function (`() => import(...)`) as `:is` binding for your dynamic component, and this function gets executed repeatedly in an endless loop.

To dynamically load components in a loop, you should use a computed property to resolve the component dynamically, and then use that computed property in the `:is` binding.

Comment: How does the computed property look like? A computed property wouldn't have a parameter that I need for the correct path

Comment: Computed property cannot take parameter as input. Using method may work

Comment: Oh, we can form the whole `users` object with an added new `component` property. Did that solve the case?

Comment: I got the solution. I created a global component "UserComp.vue" where I can have the computed property. Many thanks for help, that saves my day.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know why but returning components from methods and feeding to `is` prop does not work. This way may be a bit wacky as we need to import all components at the start, but may help the case.

```js
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <template v-for="(user, idx) in users">
      <component :key="idx" :is="`${user.name}User`" />
    </template>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "App",
  components: {
    ClickUser: () => import("./components/ClickUser.vue"),
    GotoUser: () => import("./components/GotoUser.vue"),
    SearchUser: () => import("./components/SearchUser.vue"),
  },
  data() {
    return {
      users: [{ name: "Click" }, { name: "Goto" }, { name: "Search" }],
    };
  },
};
</script>
```

Since we know what components may get used, we can import all of them first and then just use the string concatenation as the `is` prop of the `component`.

Comment: We are working a lot with inheritance (typescript) where we have "base"-classes. So in many cases we don't know the components to import. So the target is to have a solution that loads components by a path with a predefined name Pattern.

Comment: Yeah, I also didn't liked this approach :D just curious how you managed it.